# knockout js if binding and scripts

Tags: knockout.js

I am having an issue with the knockoutjs if binding.  I use the binding quite liberally because it allows me to reference sub properties in my bindings without errors.

The one cause for concern is registering event handlers and so forth on DOM elements which are added by the if binding.  Basically I need to get a callback when the elements added by the if binding are added to the DOM.  I have tried using the livequery jquery plugin but it seems like the elements are being added twice.  I came up with some example code to show this.

The knockout docs clearly state:

"The if binding, however, physically adds or removes the contained markup in your DOM, and only applies bindings to descendants if the expression is true."

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

However in the following code, the alert in the inline script IS executed:

JS:

```
var vm = {
    val: ko.observable(false),
    someText: ko.observable("some text"),
};

ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("d1")
```

HTML:

```
<div id="d1" data-bind="if: val">
   <span data-bind="text: someText"></span>
   <script>alert("here")</script>
</div>​
```

Comment: So I think I see what is going on here.  First the HTML is added to the DOM.  If the if binding is false, than the descendant HTML is removed.  When the if binding becomes true again, the HTML is added again.  I think this is why I am seeing two triggers in my livequery callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have essentially answered your own question with this quote:

> "The if binding, however, physically adds or removes the contained
>   markup in your DOM, and only applies bindings to descendants if the
>   expression is true."

While this quote clearly indicates the behavior of bindings, it does not state anything about other JavaScript or browser functionality. This makes perfect sense since Knockout's domain are its bindings and nothing else. By the time Knockout has been loaded, your browser will have already executed that alert-statement. And it will execute that alert-statement every time Knockout adds it back to the DOM-tree.

Using `<script>` elements like this in combination with Knockout is bad practice and can lead to unpredictable behavior. What you want to do is express the intended behavior in the domain of Knockout, which are its bindings. In your case, this would fit the `afterRender` binding:

```
<div id="d1" data-bind="if: val">
   <span data-bind="text: someText, afterRender: alert('here')"></span>
</div>​
```

If `val` is `true` then the inner `<span>` is rendered and the `afterRender` event will fire.

If `val` is `false` then the inner `<span>` will be **not** be rendered and the `afterRender` event will **not** fire.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out what I needed to do.  Apparently the 'if' binding is really a native/simplified extension of the template binding:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

The template binding also has the afterRender option which you can pass a function which will be executed after the entire template is added to the DOM.

My code now looks like this:

```
<div data-bind="template: {if: val, afterRender: func}">
```

Note:

This will also work using the 'with' binding and of course the 'foreach' binding.